# EasyZoom - issues with CSS and markup context

Tags: javascript, css, easyslider

It appears that I have everything setup correctly per the documentation. I'm not receiving JavaScript errors and I can see the markup change when I interact with the DOM. However, I do notice when I hover over the thumbnail, the larger image stays positioned at 0, 0. When I remove the easyzoom.css file, the larger image will start to move along the Y axis. I'm also having a hard to getting the plugin to work properly in a demo - http://codepen.io/jurbank/pen/QbbyGv

Based on the issues above, how do I get EasySlider to work as shown in the documentation.

```
<div class="easyzoom">
<a href="http://i-like-robots.github.io/EasyZoom/example-images/1_zoom.jpg">
    <img src="http://i-like-robots.github.io/EasyZoom/example-images/1_standard.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

```
var $easyzoom = $('.easyzoom').easyZoom();
var api = $easyzoom.data('easyZoom');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there but you need to add the `easyzoom--overlay` class to the five with the class `easyzoom`.

Working CodePen, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVVMOR

Comment: I see it's working in CodePen now. But in my project the .easzyzoom-flyout > img is still positioned at 0, 0; If I remove the easyzoom.css file, it moves vertically but not horizontally. It seems as though removing the css gets me farther. Perhaps it has to do with the wrapping elements. Maybe it is restrained to the width of the parent div.

Comment: I was able to replicate the issue in CodePen: - http://codepen.io/jurbank/pen/gppLKv

I'm using Zurb Foundation and it looks like the Foundation CSS is conflicting with EasyZoom. Now you can see, it stays at position: 0, 0; when you hover over the box.